# Powershell: get data out of array and put it into into new array

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to get data out of an array by using following command:

```
$newarray = $current_ds2_data -match $codenumber
```

In this case the $current_ds2_data is an array as a result of the "Import-Csv" command and the $codenumber contains the value I want to search for in the array. This work OK.

Following is an example of the value of $newarray:

```
P_SYS_InternalName  : #D_OCEV_ABC-
P_OCEV_Price        : 0.15
P_NDS_ValidPN       : 12345678
P_OCEV_PriceUnit    : 
P_NDS_VersionNumber : 1
```

Now I want to modify the value of the P_OCEV_Price field by doing

```
$newarray.P_OCEV_Price = 0.2
```

however this doesn't seem to work. It appears that $newarray.P_OCEV_Price contains no value. Somehow PS doesn't recognize P_OCEV_Price to be a cell of the array.

I also tried using

```
$newarray.["P_OCEV_Price"] = 0.2
```

to comply with hash-table formating

Next to this I tried defining the $newarray explicitly as an array or hash-table by using

```
$newarray = @()
```

or

```
$newarray = @{}
```

So far nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `$newarray` variable is an array, you won't be able to use the simple `$newarray.P_OCEV_Price` syntax to change that value. Here are two alternate options that may help you, depending on your source data:

```
# Change the price of the first matching item
$newarray[0].P_OCEV_Price = 0.2

# Change the price for all matching items
$newarray | Foreach-Object { $_.P_OCEV_Price = 0.2 }
```

In cases like this, I usually like to point out that arrays of size 1 are easy to confuse with single objects in Powershell. If you try looking at `$newarray` and `$newarray[0]` with simple output statements the results will probably look identical. It's a good idea to keep `GetType()` handy in these cases.

```
# This will show a type of Object[]
$newarray.GetType()

# The type here will show PSCustomObject instead
($newarray[0]).GetType()
```

Comment: Yup, that does the trick. Thanks so much for your swift response!!